# Spring Statemachine - building hierarchical state machine from UML

Tags: spring-statemachine

**Short:** Is it possible to create hierarchichal (nested) statemachine UML diagram in Papyrus and then use it to build working statemachine instance?

**Explained:**

Simple example without nested states, [as in documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#sm-papyrus), is working correctly.

I tried two ways to create nested state:

1. creating state in my main machine and linking another submachine to it (Properties -> Submachine)
2. creating everything in single state machine, creating state with substates

In both cases, created Spring statemachine does not recognize submachine states.

When I list all states in my application with this code:

```
public List<String> getAllStates() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Collection<State<String, String>> states = machine.getStates();
    for (State state : states) {
        Collection<State<String, String>> substates = state.getStates();
        for (State<String, String> substate : substates) {
            list.add(substate.getIds().toString());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

, it lists only two states, INITIALIZATION and PROCESSING. When I send events, machine enters from INITIALIZATION to PROCESSING, not to [PROCESSING, PREPARATION].

Am I doing something incorrectly or am I trying to do something that is not even implemented by Spring Statemachine? That is, is it possible to only create single level state machines from UML diagrams?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Janne Valkealahti for reading this question and for assuring that spring-statemachine has this option.

It seems it was my fault after all, but I'm not sure where and how (several similar diagrams were created / edited with no success). Possibly it was linked with some Papyrus / Eclipse warnings and errors on my Fedora 24 that occurred yesterday. 
Today, after creating new diagram from scratch, everything is working as expected. [Here is new, working, diagram, for which state machine lists all states and substates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4N1b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linking submachine doesn't work yet but work for that is happening in [Support for UML Sub State Machines #121](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/121).

Substates need to be configured within a single machine as you tried. Uml test source for this is at [simple-submachine.uml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-uml/src/test/resources/org/springframework/statemachine/uml/simple-submachine.uml). If you post your uml xml I can look if there's anything obvious missing(or put all 3 papyrus files, di, notation, uml) somewhere(github gist maybe) so that I can open it in papyrus.